# posh-git colors not set for some local repos

Tags: git, github, posh-git

I have two local repos for which I use posh-git, and in one of them, the branch colors show correctly according to the [posh-git readme](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git):

> - Cyan means the branch matches its remote
> - Green means the branch is ahead of its remote (green light to push)
> - Red means the branch is behind its remote
> - Yellow means the branch is both ahead of and behind its remote

But in my other repo, the branches are always in a cyan color, regardless of the state of local vs. remote.

Between the two, I've run a diff on both `$GitPromptSettings` and `git config -l`, and neither show any color-related differences (only the remote origin, some branch names, and one of them has some gitflow settings).

If it could make any difference, the two are also from two separate GitHub private (organization) repos.

What could be causing this, or what else could I do to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your local branches aren't set to *track* anything upstream. This means that Git doesn't know which remote branches to compare them against.

You can check this by inspecting the `.git/config` file inside your repository. Branches that are set to track upstream branches will contain a `merge` setting, e.g.

```
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

One easy way to set a tracking branch is to use the `-u` argument the next time you `push`, e.g. `git push -u origin master`. (You don't have to do this every time; this will set the option shown above the first time you use it).

From [its documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> `-u`
> `--set-upstream`
>
> For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less [`git-pull`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) and other commands. For more information, see `branch.<name>.merge` in [`git-config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

More information about setting a remote tracking branch on an existing branch can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/354577).

Comment: This is it. However, when creating and pushing a new branch, tracking doesn't seem to be getting set by default. Shouldn't it, and if not, can I set this as a default?

Comment: @JeradRose, Git is very flexible and generally tries not to assume things. You might have multiple remotes (e.g. a shared GitHub repository and a Heroku site that you deploy to), so Git doesn't set an upstream tracking branch by default. How would it know which one you want to use? Also, your local branch might track an upstream branch with a different name (perhaps your local `foo` branch should track `jerad/foo` in a shared repo). Generally I would recommend using the `-u` option the first time you push a branch.